# Unix command to save QuickTime Player recordings into custom folder

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video, quicktime

Using MacOS Ventura 13.5

Is there a Terminal command for macOS to specify a custom saving directory for QuickTime player videos?

For **screenshots** I use:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "<path></path>"
```

What would be the equivalent for **quick time videos/recordings**?

`ps aux | grep com.apple.quick` yields these paths for QuickTime:

- /System/Applications/QuickTimePlayer.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.quicktimeplayer.SharedPrefsVendor.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.quicktimeplayer.SharedPrefsVendor
- /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLookThumbnailing.framework/Support/com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent

Tried to modify it to my needs:

`defaults write com.apple.quicktimeplayer.SharedPrefsVendor location "~/Desktop/video_recording"`

to no avail.

Using the UI. Upon each screen recording I have to select the custom target folder regardless of having clicked on "Remember Last Selection". The 2nd time I try to record the screen, it no longer saves the recordings in the specified folder.

Steps to activate "Remember Last Selection"

*QuickTime Player > File > New Screen Recording > Options > Remember Last Selection*

Comment: Your edit makes things even more confusing. To set a `defaults` you need the app's BundleID, not the path to the executable. You then, of course, need to know what `defaults` it will accept… You wouldn't expect an app that presents a save dialog to have a defaults save location, only a last location.

Comment: The "Remember last location" is also skewed, after setting it it duplicates the recording in my target folder and the default Desktop folder.

Comment: I still don't see any 'remember last location'. Where is that?

Comment: Apologies, it's "Remember Last Selection" which is visible when you click on "Options"

Answer (score 0):

As @Tetsujin pointed out, there's only one location for "Screen Captures" on Macs, no matter if it was captured as Screenshot or -recording. Therefore

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "<path></path>"
```

is the correct command for BOTH. You could probably write a script which moves your recordings to a different location afterwards.

Comment: OP seems to be using the old Quicktime Player for this, rather than the Screenshop app. The Player app doesn't have a default location, it has a 'live' Save file-picker dialog.

Comment: @Tetsujin exactly, am using QuickTime Player defaultly  shipped with MacOs.

Comment: There is also a `location-last` key, which stores the ... last used location. (Used by the "Remember Last Location" setting.

Comment: Where is everybody seeing this "Remember Last Location"???

Comment: @Tetsujin open the QuickTime Player > File > New Screen Recording > Options > Remember Last Selection

Comment: Last selection is not last location, btw.  I've just tested this on two Macs, one Mojave which doesn't have that option & the other Ventura… which I just discovered presents the same interface as cmd/shift/5 - the old QT screen recorder is completely gone.

Comment: Am using Ventura 13.5, the QuickTime Player is there, not sure which old one are you mentioning constantly? It's not directly visible when you click on the app but you should see in the dock.

Comment: I launch the QT Player app, select New Screen Recording - I get the same interface as the picture in my answer. I don't get the old https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cev7K.png at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin exactly, that's what I get as well, and upon each recording I need to specify the target folder otherwise it falls back to the default one, which is annoying I cannot seem to set a fixed target location.

Comment: We've already covered this then. Because you set a `defaults` you're overriding the app behaviour. You need to delete the defaults.

Comment: @Tetsujin
Hm but it's not saved in the defaults which I specified under Unix, it's rather using a different path.

Comment: Just delete your defaults & it will go back to normal behaviour. You've been writing random defaults - who knows what you've changed

Comment: @Tetsujin I deleted but it was said earlier that com.apple.screencapture is not responsible for QuicTime, QuickTime uses its own paths. Anyways for the help but nothing has solved the issue.

Comment: I didn't realise at the time that QT was simply invoking Screencapture, but your attempts to add defaults to some random file were never going to work. We have already established that the screencapture location is a single setting for both file types.

Comment: So, just to confirm: This link https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/quicktime-player/qtp97b08e666/mac#:~:text=In%20the%20QuickTime%20Player%20app%20on%20your%20Mac%2C%20choose%20File,clicks%20in%20the%20screen%20recording is describing the same thing > QuickTime Screen recording is the same as using cmd+shift+5. So by changing defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "<path></path>" you change the path for Quicktime as well.

Comment: It seems CMD+SHIT+5 invokes some other recording app. Because using the quick time player via UI saves it on the default path whereas the key shortcut indeeds saves the video to com.apple.screencapture location where my screenshots are stored.
Anyways I guess the separation of recordings and screenshots is impossible?